# incompatible types in a class iterator

Tags: java, arrays, oop, linked-list, iterator

in an exercise i was asked to create an array of linked lists of type string- LinkedList[] in java. in order to do this i created a wrapper class with a property of a LinkedList called a Bucket and created an array of buckets instead. this is the bucket class:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;

/**
 * A class representing a bucket in an open hash set of strings.
 * It's a wrapper-class that has a LinkedList<String> that delegates methods to it.
 */
public class Bucket implements Iterable{
    private LinkedList<String> listOfStrings = new LinkedList<>();

    //Methods

    /**
     * @param searchValue a string to check.
     * @return true if the property listOfString contains searchValue false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean contains (String searchValue) {
        return listOfStrings.contains(searchValue);
    }

    /**
     * @param newValue A string to add to the property listOfString.
     * @return true if newValue wasn't in the list and was added successfully, false other wise.
     */
    public boolean add (String newValue){
        if (contains(newValue)){
            return false;
        } else {
            listOfStrings.add(newValue);
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param toDelete a string to delete from the property listOfString.
     * @return true if the String was in the property listOfString and was deleted successfully false
     * otherwise.
     */
    public boolean delete (String toDelete){
        if (contains(toDelete)){
            listOfStrings.remove(toDelete);
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> iterator(){
        return listOfStrings.iterator();
    }


}
```

The bucket class delegates methods from LinkedList so i'll be able to use it as an array of linked lists. the problem starts when i try to iterate over it:

```
simpleHashArray = new Bucket[newTableSize];//an array of Buckets
for (Bucket bucketToCheck : simpleHashArray){
    for(String stringToAdd : bucketToCheck){
        add(stringToAdd);
    }
}
```

in the second for there's an error: incompatible types. for some reason it expects type Object instead of type String.

do you know why? what should i do?
thanks!

Comment: Change `Iterable` to `Iterable<String>` so it expects to iterate of Strings.

Answer (score 2):

`Iterable` is a generic interface in java. This means it is parameterized over types and expects specific type parameter to identify types of objects in an underlying collection. If you omit type parameter you simply get `Iterable<Object>`.

To be able to work with `Strings` in your collection without explicit casting, change your `Bucket` declaration to:

```
public class Bucket implements Iterable<String> {
...
}
```